# How to I resolve a deprecation issue?

Tags: ansible

I'm creating Ansible Playbook for IT Automation.

This is the console output, I am getting:

```
Apache web server.

web.yml
- hosts: 192.168.1.80
  remote_user: ksouthall
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
  - name: Install Apache
    apt:
      name: apache2
      update_cache: yes
  - name: Copying the demo file
    template: src=/etc/ansible/index.html dest=/var/www/html
              owner=www-data group=www-data mode=0644


ansible-playbook web.yml -f 1 --ask-become-pass
BECOME password:
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The TRANSFORM_INVALID_GROUP_CHARS settings is set to allow bad characters
in group names by default, this will change, but still be user configurable on deprecation. This
feature will be removed in version 2.10. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting
deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
 [WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see
details

 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: 192.168.1.80


PLAY [192.168.1.80] ******************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************
```

**Question**: Is the BECOME password my system password?

Comment: Someone already reported the lack of documentation as a bug at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/56930 --- follow this one to get it fixed. Yep, dash use is likely the issue.

Answer (score 13):

Most likely you have dashes in your inventory group names.

Check your inventory file (default is /etc/ansible/hosts) and remove invalid characters from the group names, characters which are not **letters**, **digits** or **underscore** are considered invalid.
(Also group names starting with digits are invalid)

See:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#transform-invalid-group-chars

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.0/lib/ansible/config/base.yml#L1489

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.0/lib/ansible/constants.py#L122

Comment: Removing the invalid character, reesolved the issue. Now I get; [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: 16.83.62.83

Comment: That is because your inventory does not contain "16.83.62.83", create an inventory file and put that host inside, then you can run your playbook using: ansible-playbook web.yml -i my_inventory_file.yml

Comment: Resolved the match issue. Now I get this: [WARNING]: Updating cache and auto-installing missing dependency: python-apt

Comment: Install python-apt / python3-apt in the host you are trying to run the apt ansible module in. (sudo apt install python-apt). see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html#requirements

Comment: Does the ansible docs list "characters which are not **letters**, **digits**, or **underscore** are considered invalid" anywhere? I see you've linked the source code which defines it, but I was wondering if it's also in the docs. I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names

and https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#transform-invalid-group-chars

The docs might need some enhancement to make it clearer.

Comment: Agreed. The docs don't mention that group names *are* variables, so it's not clear that the group names must follow the same conventions. I've opened up [PR#69285](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/69285) to update the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

For `--ask-become-pass` you need to enter the password for your user on the remote box (assuming you have root-level privilege on that box).